# What is "dithreitol"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, analytical-chemistry, reference-request, identification

The article by Hu et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1177/154405910608501212)] mentions a compound "*dithreitol*" in the *Saliva Proteome Analysis* section (emphasis mine):

> For the "shotgun" approach, saliva samples (1 mL) were pre-fractionated with the use of Millipore ultracentrifuge filters (Millipore Corp., Billerica, MA, USA).
>   Individual fractions were treated with 10 mM **dithreitol** for 30 min and then 50 mM iodoacetamide for 30 min.

[PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=dithreitol) doesn't reveal any details as to what this compound exactly is and suggests alternative spelling, e.g. [D-threitol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/169019).

[Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22dithreitol%22) results in several mentions of this compound in the literature, but I didn't find any further details except that it's probably a [sulfhydryl reagent](https://books.google.com/books?id=7JcnWmCB7EIC&q="dithreitol"&dq="dithreitol"&hl=en&redir_esc=y).
This makes me think that "*dithreitol*" could be another name for [dithiothreitol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithiothreitol), but I didn't manage to find any solid references to support this proposition.

To sum it up: what is *dithreitol*, exactly, and what chemical and structural formulas does it posses?

#### References

1. Hu, S.; Li, Y.; Wang, J.; Xie, Y.; Tjon, K.; Wolinsky, L.; Loo, R. R. O.; Loo, J. A.; Wong, D. T. Human Saliva Proteome and Transcriptome. *J Dent Res* **2006**, 85 (12), 1129–1133. DOI: [10.1177/154405910608501212](https://doi.org/10.1177/154405910608501212).

Comment: In some papers, like this https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3139612/, are mentioned urea-dithreitol-sodium lauryl sulphate (UDS) and urea-dithiothreitol (UDT). If you google "uds urea lauryl", you get many results which define UDS as the ingredients above plus dithiothreitol. So I guess that is just a kinky name for dithiothreitol.

Comment: @The_Vinz If you found an article that *explicitly* states that dithreitol≡dithiothreitol, please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @andselisk, It is most likely a spelling mistake which is not uncommon. If SciFinder does not list it (as written) then it is not a standard name. I got zero results.

Comment: @M.Farooq I agree it could be a typo if the term is encountered in a single place or two. Here, we are dealing with several dozens (if not hundreds) entries for the textbooks ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22dithreitol%22)) and papers ([Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22dithreitol%22&as_sdt=800000000001&as_sdtp=on)). This is weird.

Comment: @andselisk, Could you locate the original method of the procedure used by the authors? It is a chain mistake and other people blindly quoted the same name for dithiothreitol. The same thing happens for references. Believe it or not there are so many (mostly minor) mistakes in the published works that one cannot imagine. My boss used to say "Paper never refused an ink"...meaning you can write whatever you want, the paper won't say anything.

Comment: It's probably a typo- there is no other good explanation: (1) dithreitol could be a misstyped version of "D-threitol" (2) dithreitol could be a synonym (redundant) of threitol (3) dithreitol could refer to a covalent dimer of threitol, say an ether, or  longer polyol. Given that the context in which the compound appears is often as a buffer additive, often in texts in which the purported compound acts as a (thiol) reducing agent, the best explanation is that "dithreitol" is a typographical error where DTT should have stood.

Comment: DTT is very commonly used. It is interesting that the (puported) error arises so often, but some typos should not seem entirely strange, given the frequency with which DTT is reported used, the ease with which the typo can be committed, and the ease with which it could be overlooked or ignored as insignificant.

Answer (score 3):

> For the "shotgun" approach, saliva samples ($\pu{1 mL}$) were pre-fractionated with the use of Millipore ultracentrifuge filters (Millipore Corp., Billerica, MA, USA). Individual fractions were treated with $\pu{10 mM}$ dithreitol for $\pu{30 min}$, and then $\pu{50 mM}$ iodoacetamide for $\pu{30 min}$.

This reaction sequence in Ref.1 has a clear intention: First, break disulfide bonds in saliva proteins using a thiol exchanging reagent and then trap the recently formed thiol groups by iodoacetamide (Ref.2). According to Ref.2:

> Alkylation of cysteine thiols with iodo, bromo or chloro substituted acetic acid or acetamide is a classic approach that has been exploited since the 1930′s.

Thus, it is safe to assume that this second reaction is intended to trap thiol group as quickly as possible (The relative reaction rates between glutathione and these halogenated acetates are $100:60:1$ for iodo-, bromo- and chloro-acetates respectively; Ref.3).

Also keep in mind that disulfide reduction to corresponding thiol is accomplished primarily by thiol exchange type reagents such as dithiothreitol (DTT) or 2-mercaptoethanol (ME). Thus, it is also safe to assume that dithreitol mentioned in Ref.1 is definitely a thiol exchanging reagent, possibly DTT. Therefore, I think it is a chain mistake as M. Farooq suggested in his comment.

**References:**

1. S. Hu, Y. Li, J. Wang, Y. Xie, K. Tjon, L. Wolinsky, R. R. O. Loo, J. A. Loo, D. T. Wong, "Human Saliva Proteome and Transcriptome," *J. Dent. Res.* **2006**, *85(12)*, 1129–1133 (DOI: 10.1177/154405910608501212).
2. Jakob R. Winther, Colin Thorpe, "Quantification of Thiols and Disulfides," *Biochimica et Biophysica Acta* **2014**, *1840(2)*, 838-846 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bbagen.2013.03.031).
3. Frank Dickens, "CLII. Interaction of halogenacetates and SH compounds. The reaction of halogenacetic acids with glutathione and cysteine. The mechanism of iodoacetate poisoning of glyoxalase," *Biochem J.* **1933**, *27(4)*, 1141–1151 (doi: 10.1042/bj0271141).

Comment: One of the publication in andselisk's search even had the CAS number, "dithreitol, 3483-12-3". Another publication had "dithio dithreitol". Many publications have something like "dithreitol (DTT)". It reminds me of mis-citations of https://www.nature.com/articles/227680a0.